# FFmpeg check downloaded stream

Tags: ffmpeg, playlist, http-live-streaming

I'm downloading a m3u8 stream like this:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:5
#EXT-X-ALLOW-CACHE:YES
#EXT-X-PLAYLIST-TYPE:VOD
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:1
#EXTINF:1.000,
seg-1.ts
#EXTINF:2.000,
seg-2.ts
#EXTINF:3.000,
seg-3.ts
#EXTINF:5.000,
seg-4.ts
```

ffmpeg -i "https://example.com/mystream.m3u8" -c copy "videoname.mp4"

But, sometimes some segments are lost (http request may return an error). Are there any options to retry a connection if it failed?

Comment: It doesn't seem to retry requests on error. Needs a patch.